Blue and red cards question
Question: we have a deck with 26
cards. There are 13
red cards numbered 1−13
and 13
blue, also numbered 1−13
. Before drawing, 7
of the blue cards are removed from the deck (uniformly at random). Now you draw a card uniformly at random from the remaining 19
. Given that it is a 3
, what is the probability that it is blue?
My Solution:

Let $X=B$ be the event that the drawn card is blue and $X=3$ is the event that the drawn card is a $3$. Then $P(X=B|X=3) = \frac{P(X=3|X=B)P(X=B)}{P(X=3)}$
$P(X=B) = \frac{6}{19}$
Let $A$ be the event that a blue 3 wasn't removed. Then $P(X=3|X=B) = P(X=3|A \cap X=B)P(A|X=B) + P(X=3|A^C \cap X=B)P(A^C|X=B)$
$P(X=3|A^C \cap X=B) = 0$ and $P(X=3|A \cap X=B) = \frac{1}{6}$ because there are $6$ blues left and one of them is a $3$.
$P(A|X=B) = \frac{6}{13}$ since there are $6$ possible spaces for the blue 3 to go in for it to not get removed.
So $P(X=3|X=B) = \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{6}{13} = \frac{1}{13}$
$P(X=3) = P(X=3|X=B)P(X=B) + P(X=3|X=R)P(X=R)$. $P(X=3|X=R) = \frac{1}{13}$ and $P(R) = \frac{13}{19}$
So putting it all together, $P(X=3) = \frac{1}{13} \times \frac{6}{19} + \frac{1}{13} \times \frac{13}{19} = \frac{1}{13}$
Therefore $P(X=B|X=3) = \frac{\frac{1}{13} \times \frac{6}{19}}{\frac{1}{13}} = \frac{6}{19}$

Is this correct and if not, where did I go wrong?
Thanks.

Given the set up, the only way it is blue is if the blue $3$ survives the removal and is then drawn.   That happens with probability $\frac 6{13}\times \frac 1{19}$.  As you remark, the probability that you draw a $3$ is $\frac 1{13}$ (each rank is equally likely, after all) so you divide by $\frac 1{13}$ to arrive at the answer you found.

Please review https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info and the links there to learn about what types of questions are suitable here.

More intuitively:  knowing the specific rank conveys no information.  The answer has to be the same regardless of which rank is specified.  As there are $6$ blue cards out of the $19$, the answer must then be $\frac 6{19}$.
After all, $$P(\text {Blue})=\sum_{i=1}^{13} P(\text {Blue}\,|\,i)\times P(i)$$
Where $i$ refers to event "you draw a card of rank $i$".
$P(i)=\frac 1{13}$ and the conditional probabilities are all equal.

@trueblueanil   True, that's why the answer isn't $\frac 12$ as it would be if you didn't do the removal initially.

@trueblueanil  For what?  The probability that you draw the blue $3$ conditioned on the blue $3$ surviving the removal?  But that probability is $\frac 1{19}$ since each surviving card is equally likely to be selected.

@trueblueanil  Each blue card has a $\frac 6{13}\times \frac 1{19}$ chance of being chosen.  Each red card has a $\frac 1{19}$ chance of being chosen.

@trueblueanil  Not following.  Again, it is not clear what your formula is meant to be computing.  I thought it was meant to be "the (unconditioned) probability of drawing the blue $3$ in the end."  If so, the answer to that is obviously not $\frac 3{13}$, that's far too big.  The answer to that question is $\frac 6{13}\times \frac 1{19}$.   To deduce the conditional probability given that you saw a $3$ (as requested in the problem) you must divide this by $\frac 1{13}$, the probability that you see a $3$ in the end.

As @lulu points out, the fact that we drew a $3$ is completely irrelevant. There is nothing special about the number $3$. So the question reduces to: What is the probability that a random card drawn from the depleted deck is blue?

You shouldn't use the same variable $X$ to describe different events; e.g., $X = B$ and $X = 3$ is not good practice.
Rather, define one random variable, say $C \in \{0,1\}$, that represents the color of a randomly drawn card, where $C = 1$ is the event that the card is blue, and $C = 0$ is the event that the card is red.  Then define another random variable that denotes the rank of the card, say $X \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 13\}$.
The difficulty with conditioning on these random variables is that $7$ blue cards are removed from the deck at random and we don't know which of them were removed.  However, intuition suggests that what matters here is whether the blue $3$ was removed from the deck or not, since if it was removed, then the $3$ that was drawn must be red; otherwise, there is a chance it is blue.  So it makes more sense to condition on this event, which means that we must first determine its probability.
To this end, let us define the event $R$ to mean that the blue $3$ was removed (this is an event, not a random variable).  Then
$$\Pr[R] = \frac{7}{13}. \tag{1}$$  We denote the complementary event $\bar R$ with probability $\Pr[\bar R] = \frac{6}{13}$.
Given that the blue $3$ was removed, the probability that we draw a blue $3$ is zero; i.e. $$\Pr[C = 1 \cap X = 3 \mid R] = 0. \tag{2}$$
What is the probability that the card is a blue $3$ if the blue $3$ was not removed?  Well, there is only one blue $3$ among the $19$ cards remaining, so it is simply $$\Pr[C = 1 \cap X = 3 \mid \bar R] = \frac{1}{19}. \tag{3}$$
Next, what is the probability of drawing any $3$ (either color), given that the blue $3$ was removed?  This is
$$\Pr[X = 3 \mid R] = \frac{1}{19}. \tag{4}$$
And in the case where it was not removed,
$$\Pr[X = 3 \mid \bar R] = \frac{2}{19}, \tag{5}$$
because now we have the red $3$ and blue $3$ out of the $19$ cards remaining.
Finally, we have enough information to compute the desired probability, which is $$\begin{align}
\Pr[C = 1 \mid X = 3] &= \frac{\Pr[C = 1 \cap X = 3]}{\Pr[X = 3]} \\
&= \frac{\Pr[C = 1 \cap X = 3 \mid R]\Pr[R] + \Pr[C = 1 \cap X = 3 \mid \bar R]\Pr[\bar R]}{\Pr[X = 3 \mid R]\Pr[R] + \Pr[X = 3 \mid \bar R]\Pr[\bar R]} \\
&= \frac{0 \cdot \frac{7}{13} + \frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{6}{13}}{\frac{1}{19} \cdot \frac{7}{13} + \frac{2}{19} \cdot \frac{6}{13}} \\
&= \frac{6}{7 + 2 \cdot 6} \\
&= \frac{6}{19}. \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

Mathematica code to simulate this experiment:
Tally[Select[ParallelTable[RandomChoice[
    Join[Append[{#}, "b"] & /@ RandomSample[Range[13], 6], 
     Append[{#}, "r"] & /@ Range[13]]], 10^7], #[[1]] == 3 &]]

For me, this yielded the output
{{{3, b}, 243407}, {{3, r}, 527660}}

from which we calculate $\frac{243407}{243407+527660} = \frac{243407}{771067} \approx 0.315676$, which is close to $\frac{6}{19} \approx 0.315789$.
